# missing R.java on eclipse, android adt bundle

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I downloaded the Android ADT Bundle for Windows and downloaded all the necessary tools to go along with it. Then I started a new project but there is an error in the mainactivity.java. Now I have searched for the answers here and other sites, none has helped me so far. I know the missing file is the R.java. I read here somewhere that it was the Android Build Tools. I noticed something, when I opened the SDK Manager outside of Eclipse, the Build Tools needed are installed. But when I open the SDK Manager inside Eclipse, it's not installed. Is that supposed to be like that? So I need to update my SDK Manager inside Eclipse? And another thing, downloading from the SDK Manager is so damn slow...any tips to make it normal speed? Thanks guys!

Comment: Check the path to your sdk in Eclipse (Settings/Prefs under Android).

Answer (score 0):

R.java is created with your app. Its not anything to download. Do a Clean Project if you are having errors.

As for the internet speed, it depends on your ISP.

Comment: fixed the problem now, updated the SDK Build Tools in the Android SDK Manager inside Eclipse. It automatically fixed and loaded the R.java.